# Tool for socket visualisation

Tags: linux, sockets, visualization

Are there any tools to dynamically and graphically display the iterations between a bound socket and connected clients? Debugging issues in sockets with multiple simultaneous interactions can be a huge mess, I would think that displaying the interactions graphically would be a great help to understanding what is going on in a server's interactions.

Comment: This kickstarter does exactly what you're asking for: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1002798642/tcp-ip-bouncer

Comment: A shame this was never funded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of graphical applications per se.

However, tcpdump or (for those who require a GUI) wireshark are pretty good at showing you the packets being sent, which is what you actually want here in general.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to have a tool that sits on top of these to visualise socket information. I found this http://tnv.sourceforge.net/ however it doesn't seem to be "socket aware." If I feel inspired I may have a go at writing something myself.

Comment: I think that, in general, "visualizing" isn't what you want when you're debugging. You want a clean list of the packets exchanged through time. As with many other debugging situations, the command line is generally your friend. I'm not against GUIs in general, but I've been debugging packet traces for over 20 years with tcpdump and there is really no faster way to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Perhaps not for an experienced packet debugger such as yourself, but for less experienced coders and especially those who don't understand all the in's and out's of sockets (hur hur hur) I'd imagine a visual representation along with a tcp dump would provide a much faster environment to gain the experience necessary to be completely comfortable and more efficient using cli based debugging tools. I'm just surprised that I couldn't find any research/implementations on the topic.

Comment: What would the visual representation give you, other than fancy boxes with rounded corners showing you things you didn't understand anyway? A GUI does not substitute for education. Adding a fancy clickable interface doesn't magically convey understanding to people who don't have it. Have you even tried to use tcpdump? Have you tried wireshark? If not, on what *rational* basis are you dismissing them?

Answer (score 1):

If looking at the big picture is enough for you - process hierarchy and the connections (TCP socket, Unix domain socket, pipes) between them - you can give a try to ipcvis:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ipcvis/

The tool records process hierarchy and socket information for distinct states and then visualize new relations from state to state:

http://youtu.be/8XFKwzkexQY